# ModuleNotFoundError:No module name 'odoo.addons,base.res'

Tags: odoo-12

I got above error when I try to run the next code

```
from odoo import models, fields, api
from odoo.exceptions import ValidationError
from odoo.addons.base.res.res_request import referenceable_models
```

Answer (score 0):

Because there is no res name module present in base module thats why it is giving an error